# Full Stack Application - Where to fill non-user defined fields? | front or back?

Tags: spring, angular, web, jhipster

First of all i have to indicate that I am new to the area of Full Stack Development and I use JHipster framework to implement my app.

So, let's assume that I have a Post entity with these fields:

**Post Entity**

```
name: String,
text: String,
dateCreated: ZoneDateTime,
userID: String
```

When a user creates a Post, I want to automatically add the **dateCreated** field as well the **userID** in the Post entity that will be saved to database.
So my question is:
Where should I have to fill the model with the userID and dateCreated? In the front-end(Angular) or in the back-end(Spring)? What is the appropriate way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the values either in the front end or the back end, but note that a user could send values of their own when making the request.  This is why I would recommend implementing it in your backend if you want to ensure the data is valid.

In your entity service class (or resource if you don't use services), in the `save` method, if the ID is null then set the createdDate and userId.  You can get the user's login through SecurityUtils and query for the userId by login (UserRepository or UserService).

Comment: Thanks @JonRuddell  for the advice. I would like to edit my title so it describes better the situation, so other users who have same question to find your useful answer. What do you propose?

Comment: I would describe the fields as "non-user defined fields" or "server defined fields" or "created/user fields", something along those lines

Answer (score 1):

Since the interaction with the user happens on the front-end you must collect, and represent this data somehow on the client side. You can build an object `postVM`(that maps the input data) and send it to the backend which will use the information to build a `Post` object and persist in the database, making it an entity.

Comment: So you tell me that I have to do it in the backend?

Comment: Yes, the actual `Post` construction should be done on the backend.